# Can't debug multiple lines in a case block with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Has anyone ever seen this:

[image: c]

I have tried a few different ways but whatever I try I cannot get to the end of the case statement.  Here in the picture you can see it appears to get confused half way through.

Note that I clicked the lines to debug while the project was stopped.  But after starting it I can see a couple of those lines now have an empty circle unlike the other lines.

Any advice on this?

Comment: It looks like your source code and binary you debuging is from different versions. have you tried to rebuild all projects?

Comment: I think u are on release mode check it once

Comment: I'm in debug mode.  I will try a rebuild all.

Comment: I did a rebuild and modified the file.  Still similar results even when moving code into a method and calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: Go to Project|Properties|Build and uncheck `[ ] Optimize code`

The optimizer really frags your debugging experience.